# how to replace all instances of '*'

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this for replace all instances of `foo` with `bar`.

```
str.replace(/foo/g, "bar")
```

What if I need to replace all instances of `*` character:

```
str.replace(/*/g, "bar")
```

Javascript `/*` sees as comment starting.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the asterisk sign - `\*`:

```js
var str = '****'
var result = str.replace(/\*/g, "bar")

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `*`:

```
str.replace(/\*/g, "")
```

A `*` is a special character in a regular expression that matches the previous token zero or more times. To use it literally in a regular expression it must be escaped.

**Demo:**

```js
let str = 'lorem ip*sum do*lor sit am*et';

let result = str.replace(/\*/g, "");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: **To Downvoter:** Can you please justify your downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.

Split string by `*` and then join with `bar`

```js
var str = '****'
var result = str.split("*").join('bar')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the `*` char with `\*`, like `str.replace(/\*/g, "bar")`